# Assigned variable value always undefined

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I have this js code that will be responsible to create an hidden file input and then create a base64 from the selected file

```js
const fileReader = new FileReader()
let docxTemplate

export async function run() {
    return Word.run( async (ctx) => {
        //
        const fileInput = document.createElement('input')
        fileInput.type = 'file'
        fileInput.hidden = true
        fileInput.multiple = false
        fileInput.accept = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
        fileInput.click()
        //
        fileInput.onchange = () => {
          //the console log will return undefined
          console.log(fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]))
          fileReader.onload = () => {
             docxTemplate = fileReader.result
          }

        }
        //
        //Also this console log will return undefined
        console.log(docxTemplate)
        //
        const doc = ctx.document.body
        //
        let date = doc.search('[DATE]')
        let dateNow = dayjs().locale('it').format('D MMMM YYYY')
        console.log(dateNow)
        date.load('text')

        return ctx.sync().then( () => {
            //
        })
    })
}
```

I've created the docxTemplate variable and I want to assign the resulting base64 to it so I can use the variable with the [DocumentCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentcreated?view=word-js-preview) class of word js api. Unfortunately I'm unable to get the desired result and the variable will be set only inside the file reader onload function. How I can assign the result of the file reader correctly to the variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)